# Prepared Statement with HashMap, Exception

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, prepared-statement

need a little Help on that. Having some Problems with an Exception and I am very new in using this library. Thanks in advance :)

Error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''common_translations.name' as nm JOIN ('common_translations.name_id' as nid)

My code:

```
private DatabaseConnection db;
private final HashMap <String, String> statements;

public DatabaseReader(DatabaseConnection db) {
    statements = new HashMap<String, String>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1827340576955092045L;
    {
        put("odds","vfl::%");
        put("common_translations", "vhc::%");
        put("common_translations","vdr::%");
        put("common_translations", "vto::%");
        put("common_translations","vbl::%");
        put("common_translations", "vf::%");
        put("odds","vsm::%");
        put("odds", "rgs::%");
        put("odds", "srrgs::%");
    }};

    this.db = db;
}

public void read() {
    try {
        Connection connection = db.connect(db.getUrl_common_translation());
        PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT nm.id, nid.key, nm.name FROM ? as nm JOIN (? as nid)\r\n" + 
                "                 ON (nm.id = nid.id) where nid.key like ? and nm.typeId=8 and nm.sourceId=-1 and nm.languageCode='en'");           
        for(Entry <String,String> e : statements.entrySet()) {
            ps.setString(1, e.getKey() + ".name");
            ps.setString(2, e.getKey() + ".name_id");
            ps.setString(3, e.getValue());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                //String tag = rs.getString("tag");
                //String translation = rs.getString("translation");     
                System.out.println(id);
            }
        }



    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can't use the `?` placeholders system to replace a table name or a column name, it only works for values .

Comment: Oh okay thank you.  Do you have maybe any advice to do this in a smart way?

Comment: Well maybe you could use a `StringBuilder` to build your query String according to the targeted tables .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the name of columns with a wrong way, this :

```
ps.setString(1, e.getKey() + ".name");
ps.setString(2, e.getKey() + ".name_id");
```

Will make the input between quotes :

```
FROM "something.name" as
```

and this is a wrong syntax.

Instead you have to set the names directly without prepared statement like this :

```
Connection connection = db.connect(db.getUrl_common_translation());
PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement();
for (Entry<String, String> e : statements.entrySet()) {
    String query = "SELECT nm.id, nid.key, nm.name FROM " + e.getKey() + ".name" +" as nm "
            //----------------------------------------------^__________________^
            + "JOIN (" + e.getKey() + ".name_id" + " as nid) ON (nm.id = nid.id) "
            //-----------^_____________________^
            + "where nid.key like ? and nm.typeId=8 "
            + "and nm.sourceId=-1 and nm.languageCode='en'";
    ps.setString(1, e.getValue());
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(query);
    //------------------------------^^
```

But before this you have to check the names shouldn't contains something that infect the query(to avoid syntax error, and sql injection), so you need to make some controllers before

Answer (score 0):

From DB point of view you will try execute a query:

```
SELECT nm.id, nid.key, nm.name 
  FROM :param1 as nm 
       JOIN (:param2 as nid) ON (nm.id = nid.id) 
 where nid.key like :param3 and nm.typeId=8 and nm.sourceId=-1 and nm.languageCode='en'
```

with some parameters. But you can not pass table or view as parameter. It makes no sense.

to fix you problem you can use this snippet:

```
String sql = "SELECT nm.id, nid.key, nm.name FROM %s as nm JOIN (%s as nid)\r\n" + 
            "                 ON (nm.id = nid.id) where nid.key like ? and nm.typeId=8 and nm.sourceId=-1 and nm.languageCode='en'"
for(Entry <String,String> e : statements.entrySet()) {
    PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(
          String.format(sql, e.getKey() + ".name", e.getKey() + ".name_id")
    );           
    ps.setString(1, e.getValue());
        .... your code here ....
}
```

Comment: Well thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for :) But the Problem is this piece of code is denied by Database :/